# unpack requires a string argument of length 2

Tags: python, maya, wave

I unable to figure out whats the problem with my code

```
import wave,struct,math

waveFile = wave.open("F:/mayaSound/ChillingMusic.wav", "rb") 
volume = []

frames = waveFile.getnframes()
rate = waveFile.getframerate()
length = frames / int(rate)


for i in range (0,length):
    waveData = waveFile.readframes(1)

    data = struct.unpack("<h",waveData)
    temp = (int(data[0])-128) / 128
    volume.append(20*math.log10(abs(temp) + 1))


print volume

waveFile.close()
```

it gives me

```
Error: error: file <maya console> line 14: unpack requires a string argument of length 2 #
```

Comment: So what is your frame size? The size depends on the type of audio encoded.

Comment: The length of my audio file is 27 . this is the audio that im using https://www.dropbox.com/s/lrz5yhzbomf91r8/ChillingMusic.wav?dl=0

Comment: Thanks for the reply ..Actually im new to this stuff .i tried to struct.calcsize('<h') it gives me 2 ..but in don't know what exactly should be done to make my code workable

Comment: Thanks for the help Cristik ,i found was was the mistake ,simply had to change "<h" to "<i"